# Concatenating built files in webpack

Tags: webpack

I have the following webpack config:

```js
import path from 'path'
import pj2us from 'pj2us-transformer';
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin'
import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from 'clean-webpack-plugin'

const defaultConf = {
    name: 'default',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([ {
        from: 'package.json',
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/local.user.js',
        transform: function(content, resourcePath) {
            return pj2us(content, path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/main.js'));
        }
        } ], { })
    ]
}

export default defaultConf
```

It creates 2 files in dist: `main.js` and `local.user.js`.
**I want to merge both into a file called `merged.user.js`**

I tried this based on the `webpack-merge-and-include-globally` plugin:

```
new MergePlugin({
    files: {
        "merged.user.js": [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') + '/local.user.js',
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/main.js')
        ]
    }
})
```

It emits an empty file.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to merge them?

Comment: Incredibly convoluted. But since you asked: The 2 files are 2 parts of a userscript - metadata and code, and I need to merge them so I can symlink the result to a webdav server which syncs to my userscript manager so I can develop locally, because the normal way of doing this seems to fail on certain sites with strict CSP, specifically disallowing `eval`, because the @require header used to enable local dev uses eval to execute its required file, but only for the file schema for some reason, which I don't know, and because it's unlikely to be fixed I must find a workaround. Satisfied? 

Comment: you cant merge out of the process itself, your will need to separate the merge task from generating it.